# OOP: Method for cout output

Tags: c++, cout

I have to create a method, which prints all collected data's on screen, here is my try:

```
bool UnPackedFood::printer() {

        cout << " -- Unpacked Products --" << endl;

        cout << "barcode: " << getBarcode() << endl;
        cout << "product name: " << getBezeichnung() << endl << endl;
        cout << "weight: " << getGewicht() << endl;
        cout << "price" << getKilopreis() << endl;

    return true;
}
```

**In my main:**

```
UnPackedFood upf;
cout << upf.printer();
```

This shows me the correct output, but it still delivers me a bool value back, which I actually dont need. I tried to declare the method as void, but thats not working.

Comment: Have you tried `upf.printer();` instead of `cout << upf.printer();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three possible solutions:

1. Don't do `cout << upf.printer();`, the output is not needed since the function itself does the output.
2. Instead of writing to the output in the `printer` function, append to a string and return the string.
3. Make an overloaded `operator<<` for `UnPackedFood`, so you can just do `std::cout << upf;`

Comment: I wouldnt suggest building a string. Instead, I would suggest passing a stream. That way you could use `upf.printer(cout);`, or: `stringsteam s; upf.printer(s);` and use `s.str()` to use the string for other means.

Comment: @JArkinstall That would be an upvote-worthy answer if you posted it as one (of course a little bit more complete than the comment). :)

Comment: @JArkinstall That's a fourth possible solution. Though in that case I would rather favor alternative 3 in my answer. :)

Comment: I agree - overloading `<<` is preferable IMO. There are cases when passing a stream is favourable (such as if there are various output methods or arguments to printer()). In these cases, though, a view class would probably be more suited to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should overload `<<` operator for output stream. Then when you type `cout << upf` it will print your product.

Take a look at [this example](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/) and try to do something similar to following snippet:

```
class UnPackedFood {   
    ...
    public:
       ...
       friend ostream & operator<< (ostream &out, const UnPackedFood &p);
};

ostream & operator<< (ostream &out, const UnPackedFood &p) {
        out << " -- Unpacked Products --" << endl;
        out << "barcode: " << p.getBarcode() << endl;
        out << "product name: " << p.getBezeichnung() << endl << endl;
        out << "weight: " << p.getGewicht() << endl;
        out << "price" << p.getKilopreis() << endl;
        return out;
}
```

Comment: I'm able to use this within a method printer(),? Because the task was to print out the products in the method printer().

Comment: In that case just return `string` from `printer()` or do not use your current implementation with `cout`.